# Deploying Spring boot app to digital ocean

Tags: spring-boot, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy spring boot app written using jhipster to digital ocean. I user tomcat manager to deploy. The deployment went fine and I am able to access the html pages, but my rest apis are not accessible. I get 404 when I try to access any rest api.

I also don't know where my application startup logs are going (they are not there in localhost-access.$date.log) file under logs directory. AM I missing any configuration?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with my droplet's limited RAM and memory. I noticed the JVM was not running. When I increased size of RAM it started working just fine.

Comment: Can you please say what is the size of RAM that solves your issue

Comment: I upgraded to 1GB.